# Как привести тип строка к целому числу

Tags: ios, swift

Как правильно выполнить такой код? Сейчас он выдает ошибку *coalesce using '??' to provide a default when the optional value contains 'nil*

```
var s = "5"
var num = Int(s) + 1
print(num)
```

P.S.: Посоветуйте, ключевые паттерны и библиотеки для реализации приложения работающего в онлайн режиме, подключающийся к серверу, подгружающая в локальную базу данных данные и способное работать после этого в офлайне. Использовать паттерн MVVM, а локальную бд делать на основе Core Data?

Comment: в ошибке же прямо написано, что нужно сделать

Comment: Дубликат: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115141/converting-string-to-int-with-swift

Comment: Я не нашел там ответов

Comment: @Эникейщик как то так писать? `var num = (Int(s) ?? 0) + 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let s = "50"
let firstInt = Int(s) ?? 0
```

т.к. строка может содержать внутри себя нечто, что не будет числом (например, "StackOverflow"), необходимо указать, что вы хотите принудительно задать значение. Для этого используется 0.

Так же, можно использовать

```
let firstInt = (s as NSString).integerValue
```

Другой пример: Преобразуем строку в double

```
let firstDouble = (s as NSString).doubleValue
```

По ссылке, которую я приложил выше (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115141/converting-string-to-int-with-swift), представлено множество примеров, как сделать это

Касаемо MVVM паттерна снято множество видео. Один из примеров - https://youtu.be/2yMtKZb-BO0

Comment: Спасибо, это все было написано по ссылке, как сделать аналог такой записи: `summ = str(s) + 1`? Или нельзя на свифте преобразовывать строку в число и сразу использовать ее в математических операциях?

Comment: Про MVVM имелось ввиду такой используется обычно на свифте или другой

Comment: @helldrg 1 сообщение - Если вам нужно добавить 1 и вывести, просто добавьте эти действия: `var printValue = firstInt + 1` `print(printValue)`. 2 сообщение - MVVM - это паттерн. Это не какая-то программа или утилита. Это способ некий шаблон архитектурный для разработки приложения. В виде как раз таки приводится пример разработки приложения по этому шаблону

Comment: Спасибо! Получается в одну строчку нельзя преобразовывать данные и использовать их в мат операциях(

Comment: Если вы хотите хранить данные локально, это можно сделать кучей способов. MSAccess, MySql (например, через xampp), да даже банально в лоб, сериализация объектов в json и их десериализация после запуска программы

Comment: Посмотрите, что такое nil в свифте и что такое nil coalescing. Станет понятнее, почему так работает преобразование и как обращаться с nil.